# How to set top-left coordinates in DirectX 9?

Tags: c++, windows, directx, directx-9

I need to draw something in DirectX 9.
I am interested to work in a way that the coordinates will be adjusted to pixels, while (0,0) will be the **TopLeft** corner. Here is what I do:

```
RECT clientRect;
::GetClientRect(m_hWIN, &clientRect);

D3DXMATRIX matOrtho2D, matIdentity;    

D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&matOrtho2D, 0, clientRect.right, 0, clientRect.bottom, 0.0f, 1.0f);
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&matIdentity);

g_pDirect3D_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matOrtho2D);
g_pDirect3D_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matIdentity);
g_pDirect3D_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matIdentity);
```

This works fine, except the (0,0) is the **BottomLeft** corner. How can I change it?
Thanks!

Comment: swap bottom and top in D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH:
D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH(&matOrtho2D, 0, clientRect.right, clientRect.bottom, 0, 0.0f, 1.0f);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be add to code:

```
D3DXMATRIX matTranslate, matFlip;  

D3DXMatrixTranslation(&matTranslate, 0, clientRect.bottom, 0.0f);
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matFlip, D3DXToRadian(180));
D3DXMATRIX matCoordTransform = matFlip * matTranslate;

g_pDirect3D_Device->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matCoordTransform);
```